# Invert first byte in file

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the most pythonic way to change first byte of file to its inversion copy?
Now, I use this code:

```
with open(file_path, 'r+b') as f:
    b = bytearray(f.read(1))
    b[0] = ~b[0] & 255
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(b)
```

Comment: So do you have any problem with your code, by any chance?

Comment: the only change I'd make is to do `b[0] ^ 0xff` instead of `~b[0] & 255`

Comment: @Kasramvd except that looks cumbersome, yet no

Comment: @oldrinb nice catch, thx!

Comment: ..or even `b[0] ^= 255`

Comment: Probably the question should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative that uses a memory-mapped file:

```
import mmap

with open(file_path, 'r+b') as f, mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 1) as mm:
    mm[0] ^= 255
```